# In BeautifulSoup, how do I search for an element that contains text but also has an ancestor with a certain class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using BeautifulSoup 4 with Python 3.7.  I want to find an element that has the text " points" in its element, but also has an ancestor DIV whose class attribute contains "article".  I have figured out how to search for elements with text ...

```
points_elt = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(' points'))[0]
```

but I can't figure out how to expand the above to include elements with that text that also include an ancestor with the class "article."  This is an example of the element I would like to find ..

```
<div class="article class2">
    ... other elements ...
    <span class="outerSpan">
        <span class="innerSpan">2000 points</span>
    </span>
   ... other element closing tags ...
</div>
```

This is another example it should work on ...

```
<div class="article class7">
    <p>
        <div class="abc">
            <span class="outerSpan">
                <span>8000 points</span>
            </span>             
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use .parent to get the parent tag of the element. Also, I would suggest getting the element based on class name. Or even use CSS selector.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output from this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css selector and check the string you are looking after.

```
html='''<div class="article class2">
    <span class="outerSpan">
        <span class="innerSpan">2000 points</span>
    </span>
</div>
'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('.article .innerSpan'):
   if 'points' in item.text:
       print(item.text)
```

Or You can use this.

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('.article:contains(points)'):
   print(item.text.strip())
```

Comment: Will this still work if the element with the class "innerSpan" is not a direct child of the element with the class "article"?  I tried to expand my example to detail this.

Comment: @Dave Based on the example if span tag there inside div tag whose class is article should work.You can try the 2nd options as well or provide some more info if you have any concerns.

Comment: Thanks.  I added another example.  The only things that rae guaranteed is that there will be an element with the text " points" and it will have an ancestor (not necessarily the direct ancestor) whose class will include the attribute "article".  There is no guarantee there will be an immediate parent of the text with class "innerSpan."

Comment: Did you try my second options.I have provided two solutions.can you give a try the 2nd one and let me know.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = """
<div class="article class2">
    <span class="outerSpan">
        <span class="innerSpan">2000 points</span>
    </span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.findAll(text=re.compile('points$')):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
2000 points
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div class="article class2">
    <span class="outerSpan">
        <span class="innerSpan">2000 points</span>
    </span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'innerSpan'}):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
2000 points
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.  I updated my question to include another example.  But basically there is no guarantee that the element containing "points" will also have a class "innerSpan".

Answer (score 0):

```
span = soup.find_all('span')
if 'points' in span[1].text:
    div = span[1].parent.parent
    print(div)
```

span variable has all the span elements, we are traversing back to the parent of the `HTML` tag. Considering this is always the format of `HTML`.

Comment: No where in this answer are you searching for elements with the matching text, though.

Comment: I have made edits to the answer, I believe this is what you are looking for.